# How do I recover my Data?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I cut files from my system and paste them in my usb but later my usb storage got crashed and now I want to recover my files from the PC.

plz help!!

Comment: Any progress? Have you tried Testdisk and or PhotoRec?

Comment: Do you want to recover the data from your internal drive or the USB drive? What exactly does "got crashed" mean? Please [edit] your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools focusing on recovering deleted files. I do know:

- Testdisk
- PhotoRec

*The following is copied from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery) - which list more tools*

**TestDisk** and **Photorec** are both open-source data recovery utilities licensed under the terms of the GNU Public License (GPL).

**[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** is primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses, or human error, such as the accidental deletion of partition tables.

**[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)** is file recovery software designed to recover lost files including photographs (Hint: PhotographRecovery), videos, documents, archives from hard disks and CD-ROMs. PhotoRec ignores the filesystem and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even with a re-formatted or severely damaged filesystems and/or partition tables.

So - if no other input comes - check out [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) in the first step.

Comment: Note that also with testdisk you can recover data. In my case it was better than PhotoRec because I could select the exact folder to recover and so the recovery-folder took much less space in my HardDrive.